# Netgear N600 router & TP Link AV600 homeplugs

Tags: powerline-networking

I've just installed TP LInk TL-WPA4220 3 pack kit to improve wifi in other rooms in house.
All seemed OK but it has effected the speed to my imac which is connected by ethernet cable to the same Netgear n600 router as the homeplug.
I noticed this when Pokerstars started playing up as connection dropped to 26% - when I took out the ethernet cable connecting the homeplug Pokerstars immediately returned to 100% connection which is what I have always had previously.
Hope i've explained OK, i'm not very tech savvy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> All seemed OK but it has effected the speed to my imac which is
>   connected by ethernet cable to the same Netgear n600 router as the
>   homeplug. I noticed this when Pokerstars started playing up as
>   connection dropped to 26% - when I took out the ethernet cable
>   connecting the homeplug Pokerstars immediately returned to 100%
>   connection which is what I have always had previously.

The Netgear WNDR3400 only has 10/100 LAN ports while the TL-WPA4220 has 10/100/1000 ports.

> [image]
>
> [image]

[WNDR3400 Specifications](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNDR3400.aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic#tab-techspecs)

[TL-WPA4220 Specifications](http://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WPA4220.html)

Comment: The solution to drop in performance is to upgrade your router to one that has 10/100/1000 ports.

Comment: The last spec link is broken.